# Firebase server attempts to resolve http://localhost:5000/view/-B3eiIwcYV to a physical file and issues a 404 error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

So, I'm hosting a react project on firebase (issuing firebase serve or on firebaseapp.com), and have a specified react route as follows:

```html
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
....

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid} />
        <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

which if 'Single' is reloaded (browser reload) causes firebase to attempt to locate the physical location for http://{localhost or firebaseapp.com}/view/-B3eiIwcYV, which of course doesn't exist.

When I initialised my project with firebase, I specified the following option:

```html
Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? -> No
```

The generated error is as follows:

```html
-B3eiIwcYV Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the 'firebase init' process, for React Router, you do in fact want to say Yes to "Configure as a single-page app." during the 'firebase init' of your project folder.

A rewrite is added to firebase. json file:

```html
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```